# Serving all sites from different drive in xampp

Tags: xampp

I'm trying to set up xampp to use a different directory (on a different drive) as the "hub" for where my local websites are served. I basically want to set a new root folder and then use relative paths in my virtualhost declations in my vhosts file however when I tried changing the DocumentRoot in httpd.conf to the new 'hub', it seems to get ignored when I use a relative path for the DocumentRoot in virtualhost.

I looked in the error file and got the below and as you can see, not looking at the hub I had intended:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/apache/wordpress-websitename
```

Here's my changes for httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "D:\websites\_main\sites"
<Directory "D:\websites\_main\sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and an example of one of my virtualhosts:

```
    ServerName  new.websitename.com
    DocumentRoot "wordpress-websitename"
    <Directory "wordpress-websitename">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It all works fine if I use absolute paths in my virtualhost but since I'm going to have a lot of websites, it would be nice to just use a relative path for each.

Comment: One doesn't use xampp in a production environment. That said, Apache resolves relative paths with respect to its global `ServerRoot` setting. Although I strongly advise against messing with it; your installation may depend on whatever setting it currently has. The best thing here is to specify full absolute paths for each viritual host idependently. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471577/apache-configuring-server-root-for-relative-paths) for examples of use for that setting.)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I should have said in the opening post but this is purely local/testing and not for production (just me importing various websites for debugging and development and then committing changes to git)